# using index match with sum if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to link up a sumif() with an index match (i'm guessing here) but don't really know where to start.

Basically i a table with different classes of pets, their species and quantity. there are 3 stores. I need an output where i can get the quantity of each species from each store dynamically.

data table:

```
"A1"                Pet Stores      
Species  Class      a   b   c
cat      Fluffy1    1   0   0
cat      Fluffy2    3   0   0
cat      Fluffy3    5   7   1
cat      Fluffy4    6   0   7
dog      Barky1     7   6   9
dog      Barky2     1   3   9
dog      Barky3     0   2   8
dog      Barky4     0   2   3
fish     Swimmy1    0   0   0
fish     Swimmy2    1   3   0
fish     Swimmy3    0   2   3
fish     Swimmy4    0   0   0
```

Output:

```
Pet Store   a   <--change this
cat         15  <--output
dog         8   <--output
fish        1   <--output
```

right now my formula for "cat" is `=SUMIF($A$3:$A$14,A17,$C$3:$C$14)`. however, it only looks down the 1 column that i've set. how do i change it such that it searches for the "Pet Store" and returns sum of the respective column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

Formula in cell H3 copied down is

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$13,G3,INDEX($C$2:$E$13,,MATCH(H$2,$C$1:$E$1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! works wonders. this is the second time you've answered my qns. haha. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: LOL. It may not be the last time, either. Keep these questions coming!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter that @teylyn's version:

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A$13,A16,OFFSET(C$2:C$13,,CODE(B$15)-97))
```

but less versatile as it relies on the shop names being coded (which however is as in the example and makes sense for column label purposes):

[image: SO44381087 first example]

However my preference would be for a PivotTable:

[image: SO44381087 second example]

Comment: I weaned myself off Offset years ago, since it is volatile. It does not matter much in these small data samples we use in questions, but I've seen workbooks come to a screeching halt because they were constantly recalculating due to volatile functions like Offset. The pivot table is a good idea, but the source data is already a cross tab and would need to be normalised (i.e. unpivoted), so the pivot table can be filtered by either A, B or C (or using slicers).